# Batch script to move all landscape oriented photos into their own sub directory

Tags: batch-file

Suppose I have a folder that contains a bunch of image files. JPG, PNG, etc. I want to create a batch script that will:

1) loop through each file 
2) for each file, check if the image width is greater than the image height
3) if true, move into a sub-directory named landscape.

I know how to do #1 and #3, but am lost on how to go about #2.

Comment: please rephrase your question to only include details about (2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a .NET method to get the image dimensions.  Then you wouldn't need to rely on any 3rd party tools or libraries.  Here's an example that uses PowerShell hybrid code to invoke [`[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to construct a [System.Drawing.Image object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and access its dimensions.  Save it with a .bat extension and see what you think.

```perl
<# : Batch portion (PowerShell multi-line comment)
@echo off & setlocal

rem # move landscape pics to what directory?
2>NUL md landscape

for %%I in (*.jpg *.bmp *.gif *.png) do (
    call :isLandscape "%%~fI" && (
        rem # remove "echo" when satisfied that this works as desired
        echo move "%%~fI" landscape\
    ) || (
        echo %%~fI was portrait
    )
)

goto :EOF

:isLandscape <imgfile>
rem # function sets errorlevel 0 if landscape, 1 if portrait or square
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "img=%~1"
powershell -noprofile -noninteractive "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>

add-type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
$size = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile((gi $env:img)).Size
exit ($size.Width -le $size.Height) # 0 = false, 1 = true
```

---

Actually, if you aren't that attached to further processing of the files within the batch context, it'll be much faster to loop through the files within a single PowerShell session.  Save this with either a .bat or a .ps1 extension and you'll see the difference.

```perl
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

powershell -noprofile -noninteractive "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell #>

add-type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
$newdir = "landscape"

if (-not (test-path $newdir)) { md $newdir }

gci | ?{ $_.Name -match "\.(jpe?g|bmp|gif|png)$" } | %{

    $size = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_).Size
    if ($size.Width -gt $size.Height) {
        # remove the -whatif flag to enable moves
        mv $_.FullName $newdir -whatif
    } else {
        write-host ("{0} was portrait.  Not moving." -f $_.FullName) -f cyan
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CMD can't do that natively.  There are, however some 3rd party programs (IrfanView and ImageMagick to name two) with command-line options that can give you the output you need to be able to programmatically make your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageMagick and what you already have you could find width and height thusly:

```
    WIDTH="$(identify -format %w IMAGE)"
    HEIGHT="$(identify -format %h IMAGE)"
    if [ WIDTH -gt HEIGHT ]; then
      # Move image to landscape folder
    fi
```

Or use perl instead with Image::Size:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use Cwd;
    use Image::Size;
    my $landscape_dir = "/path/to/landscape_dir";
    my $Parent = shift @ARGV;
    my @img_list = map { Cwd::abs_path($_) } glob "*.jpg";
    foreach(@img_list){
      my ($w, $h) = imgsize("$_");
      if($w > $h){
        # Is landscape
        system("/bin/mv $_ $landscape_dir");
      }else{
        # Is not landscape, do something else
      }
    }
```