# Compareing Image Pixel Size in .Bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to Get file sizes of images so i can compare them to 1 of two standers 1920x1080 or 1080x1920. if my images don't match the standers i want to delete them. The reason why im trying to do this is so that when i pull images from the windows spotlight folder i can sort them and delete the file that don't match. I don't have much yet but here is my repository of code

```
xcopy %localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets C:\Users\%Username%\Pictures\"Windows Spotlight"
D
cd \
cd Users\%Username%\Pictures\"Windows Spotlight"
ren * *.jpg
```

https://github.com/CamoJackson/WinSpotlight-Copy. I looked into WMIC but i don't know enough about it. Any Ideas.

Edit: I looked at the directory and the files that im trying to use are all above 200mb and the files i don't want are under 100mb. Using ~zA i can compare that file size.

Comment: 1. Post your relevant code here by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40290822/edit) your question; providing a link is bad as links may become invalid in future (you may provide the link in addition though); furthermore, you expect help, so you should make helping you as easy as possible. 2. Windows command prompt is not capable of parsing image files, so you need some external tool for that; select one and mention it in your question (perhaps there is a related tag available for it).

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/imgInfo.bat) or [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat)

Comment: or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36585278/1683264)

Answer (score 0):

Or using BAT/VBS :

for the image dimension use the value : ***31***.

example :

***GetMediaInfo.bat "Path_to_the_folder" "Image_name" 31***

```
::GetMediaInfo.bat
::By SachaDee - 2016

::Usage
::GetMediaInfo.bat "Folder" "File" "Value of the Info to GET"

::Possible Value Example :

:: 27 = Media Duration for video or music files
:: 28 = Bits Rate in Kbs/s
:: 31 = Dimensions of an image


::Output
::Information du media
@echo off

  If not exist "#.vbs" call:construct
  For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo #.vbs "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"') do set $MediaInfo=%%a

echo %$MediaInfo%
exit/b

:construct
(echo.dim objShell&echo.dim objFolder&echo.dim objFolderItem&echo.set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application"^)&echo.set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(wscript.arguments(0^)^)&echo.set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(wscript.arguments(1^)^)&echo.dim objInfo&echo.objInfo = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, wscript.arguments(2^)^)&echo.wscript.echo objinfo)>#.vbs
```

**List of possible value (depend of the file type) :**

```
Name - 0
Size - 1
Item type - 2
Date modified - 3
Date created - 4
Date accessed - 5
Attributes - 6
Offline status - 7
Offline availability - 8
Perceived type - 9
Owner - 10
Kind - 11
Date taken - 12
Contributing artists - 13
Album - 14
Year - 15
Genre - 16
Conductors - 17
Tags - 18
Rating - 19
Authors - 20
Title - 21
Subject - 22
Categories - 23
Comments - 24
Copyright - 25
Length - 27
Bit rate - 28
Protected - 29
Camera model - 30
Dimensions - 31
Camera maker - 32
Company - 33
File description - 34
Program name - 35
Duration - 36
Is online - 37
Is recurring - 38
Location - 39
Optional attendee addresses - 40
Optional attendees - 41
Organizer address - 42
Organizer name - 43
Reminder time - 44
Required attendee addresses - 45
Required attendees - 46
Resources - 47
Meeting status - 48
Free/busy status - 49
Total size - 50
Account name - 51
Task status - 52
Computer - 53
Anniversary - 54
Assistant's name - 55
Assistant's phone - 56
Birthday - 57
Business address - 58
Business city - 59
Business P.O. box - 60
Business postal code - 61
Business state or province - 62
Business street - 63
Business fax - 64
Business home page - 65
Business phone - 66
Callback number - 67
Car phone - 68
Children - 69
Company main phone - 70
Department - 71
E-mail address - 72
E-mail2 - 73
E-mail3 - 74
E-mail list - 75
E-mail display name - 76
File as - 77
First name - 78
Full name - 79
Gender - 80
Given name - 81
Hobbies - 82
Home address - 83
Home city - 84
Home country/region - 85
Home P.O. box - 86
Home postal code - 87
Home state or province - 88
Home street - 89
Home fax - 90
Home phone - 91
IM addresses - 92
Initials - 93
Job title - 94
Label - 95
Last name - 96
Mailing address - 97
Middle name - 98
Cell phone - 99
Cell phone - 100
Nickname - 101
Office location - 102
Other address - 103
Other city - 104
Other country/region - 105
Other P.O. box - 106
Other postal code - 107
Other state or province - 108
Other street - 109
Pager - 110
Personal title - 111
City - 112
Country/region - 113
P.O. box - 114
Postal code - 115
State or province - 116
Street - 117
Primary e-mail - 118
Primary phone - 119
Profession - 120
Spouse/Partner - 121
Suffix - 122
TTY/TTD phone - 123
Telex - 124
Webpage - 125
Content status - 126
Content type - 127
Date acquired - 128
Date archived - 129
Date completed - 130
Device category - 131
Connected - 132
Discovery method - 133
Friendly name - 134
Local computer - 135
Manufacturer - 136
Model - 137
Paired - 138
Classification - 139
Status - 140
Client ID - 141
Contributors - 142
Content created - 143
Last printed - 144
Date last saved - 145
Division - 146
Document ID - 147
Pages - 148
Slides - 149
Total editing time - 150
Word count - 151
Due date - 152
End date - 153
File count - 154
Filename - 155
File version - 156
Flag color - 157
Flag status - 158
Space free - 159
Bit depth - 160
Horizontal resolution - 161
Width - 162
Vertical resolution - 163
Height - 164
Importance - 165
Is attachment - 166
Is deleted - 167
Encryption status - 168
Has flag - 169
Is completed - 170
Incomplete - 171
Read status - 172
Shared - 173
Creators - 174
Date - 175
Folder name - 176
Folder path - 177
Folder - 178
Participants - 179
Path - 180
By location - 181
Type - 182
Contact names - 183
Entry type - 184
Language - 185
Date visited - 186
Description - 187
Link status - 188
Link target - 189
URL - 190
Media created - 191
Date released - 192
Encoded by - 193
Producers - 194
Publisher - 195
Subtitle - 196
User web URL - 197
Writers - 198
Attachments - 199
Bcc addresses - 200
Bcc - 201
Cc addresses - 202
Cc - 203
Conversation ID - 204
Date received - 205
Date sent - 206
From addresses - 207
From - 208
Has attachments - 209
Sender address - 210
Sender name - 211
Store - 212
To addresses - 213
To do title - 214
To - 215
Mileage - 216
Album artist - 217
Album ID - 218
Beats-per-minute - 219
Composers - 220
Initial key - 221
Part of a compilation - 222
Mood - 223
Part of set - 224
Period - 225
Color - 226
Parental rating - 227
Parental rating reason - 228
Space used - 229
EXIF version - 230
Event - 231
Exposure bias - 232
Exposure program - 233
Exposure time - 234
F-stop - 235
Flash mode - 236
Focal length - 237
35mm focal length - 238
ISO speed - 239
Lens maker - 240
Lens model - 241
Light source - 242
Max aperture - 243
Metering mode - 244
Orientation - 245
People - 246
Program mode - 247
Saturation - 248
Subject distance - 249
White balance - 250
Priority - 251
Project - 252
Channel number - 253
Episode name - 254
Closed captioning - 255
Rerun - 256
SAP - 257
Broadcast date - 258
Program description - 259
Recording time - 260
Station call sign - 261
Station name - 262
Summary - 263
Snippets - 264
Auto summary - 265
Search ranking - 266
Sensitivity - 267
Shared with - 268
Sharing status - 269
Product name - 270
Product version - 271
Support link - 272
Source - 273
Start date - 274
Billing information - 275
Complete - 276
Task owner - 277
Total file size - 278
Legal trademarks - 279
Video compression - 280
Directors - 281
Data rate - 282
Frame height - 283
Frame rate - 284
Frame width - 285
Total bitrate - 286
```

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl  :)